Imported package is undefined eventhough it is in the node modules
I am working on react-native application. Like all JS frameworks, I have installed the packages such as formik, react-native-calendars here also. And it is visible in package.json. And also I have checked node modules directory. I can see those installed packages as well. But, sometimes When I navigate to the screen that having packages of either formik or react-native-calendars means, it crashing suddenly and it's showing formik is undefined. And sometimes it showing Maximum call stack size exceeded. I have no idea of what went wrong. Can someone please help me to fix. Thanks in advance!

You probably have a circular dependency with that package or with another package in the project that causes them not to load correctly.
You can try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge
which may help you to detect it.
It may also be because of the npm cache. Try running npm cache clean --force and install the packages again.
Hope it helps.

Tried the above, Still same issue
